# How to implement !Send or !Sync for a type?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to explicitly mark a type with unimplemented `Send` or `Sync` marker traits without some redundant fields? This can be an alternative:

```rust
struct T {
    _marker: PhantomData<*const ()>,
}
```

but again, it has a redundant field, is super cryptic (you need to remember that a pointer is `!Send + !Sync`) and might be nontrivial to get a proper combination (consider `!Sync + Send`). I believe negative trait might be a solution, but they are not available at stable yet:

```rust
// error[E0658]: negative trait bounds are not yet fully implemented
impl !Send for T {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eec8697354d27839f8606ce3d4b6a839)

Comment: What's your usecase for needing to make a type `!Send + !Sync`? Have you read [the relevant chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-04-extensible-concurrency-sync-and-send.html) in the book? Because I highly doubt this is what you are actually looking for. Apart from that, `PhantomData` seems like exactly the right tool for the job. It's not redundant, it gives the compiler the necessary information, if used correctly.

Comment: Yes, I read that doc page. I have no particular use case, just curious in the language details. `PhantomData` is mostly ok, but using a pointer inside (or other `!T`-type like MutexGuard/Rc/Ref/etc) is not obvious, the thing I prefer to avoid.

Comment: You've definitely got a point there, and there was a lot of discussion about `PhantomData` and more readable alternatives - especially in the context of variance. You won't use it a lot though, I'd go as far as saying almost never, for a typical user. You can always alias i. e. `type ForceNotSync = PhantomData<Cell<_>>`, and that is rather readable, in my opinion.

Comment: Seems like you have answered the question in the question itself. One may only extend the reasoning with the [nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/send-and-sync.html): _"Note that in and of itself it is impossible to incorrectly derive Send and Sync. Only types that are ascribed special meaning by other unsafe code can possible cause trouble by being incorrectly Send or Sync."_

Comment: One reason to need this would be a type that you *expect* to gain `!Sync` or `!Send` in the future, so for semver reasons you want to enforce it now so it's not a breaking change when it changes later.

Answer (score 11):

Your `PhantomData` solution is generally the way to do this. I was sort of surprised to see that there's no `PhantomUnsend` or `PhantomUnsync` types in `std::marker`, in the same way that there's a `PhantomPinned`; my advice would be to add, in a `util.rs` module, something resembling:

```rust
pub type PhantomUnsync = PhantomData<Cell<()>>;
pub type PhantomUnsend = PhantomData<MutexGuard<'static, ()>>;
```

These typedefs make it clear that they exist to force `!Send` or `!Sync` in types that contain them, in the same way that `PhantomPinned` forces `!Unpin`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Lucretiel 's answer. Here's another way.

```
struct UnSend(*const ());
unsafe impl Sync for UnSend {}

struct UnSync(*const ());
unsafe impl Send for UnSync {}
```

It should be noted that these definitions for `UnSend` and `UnSync` are not zero-sized. They are pointer-sized types, and can affect the alignment and layout of the containing type if used directly.

Therefore:

If you want `!Send`, you need to use like.

```
struct Foo {
    _marker: PhantomData<UnSend>,
}
```

The same to `!Sync`.