# How can I use unsync::OnceCell or unsync::Lazy for a type that is not sync?

Tags: rust

I'm looking into `once_cell`'s functionality to [lazily initialize](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/#lazy-initialized-global-data) a global/static instance. The example in the documentation focuses on the `Sync` case, i.e., it uses `sync::OnceCell` / `sync::Lazy`.

I'm wondering how that would work for a type that is not `Sync`. Simply translating the `sync::Lazy` to `unsync::Lazy` would result in (using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71945606/1804173) to emulate a non-sync type):

```rust
use once_cell::unsync::Lazy;

// Example of a type that is not sync
struct TypeNotSync {
    _marker: PhantomData<Cell<()>>,
}

static GLOBAL_DATA: Lazy<TypeNotSync> = Lazy::new(|| 
  // Let's ignore the actual initialization for now...
  unimplemented!()
);
```

This doesn't compile, and the compiler insists that the underlying type has to be `Sync`.

```
error[E0277]: `Cell<std::option::Option<fn() -> TypeNotSync>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/resources.rs:75:21
    |
75  | static GLOBAL_DATA: Lazy<TypeNotSync> = Lazy::new(|| unimplemented!());
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Cell<std::option::Option<fn() -> TypeNotSync>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `once_cell::unsync::Lazy<TypeNotSync>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `Cell<std::option::Option<fn() -> TypeNotSync>>`
    = note: if you want to do aliasing and mutation between multiple threads, use `std::sync::RwLock`
note: required because it appears within the type `Lazy<TypeNotSync>`
   --> /home/fabian/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/once_cell-1.18.0/src/lib.rs:716:16
    |
716 |     pub struct Lazy<T, F = fn() -> T> {
    |                ^^^^
    = note: shared static variables must have a type that implements `Sync`
```

The same happens when using `unsync::OnceCell` directly.

I'm a bit confused now. I'd expected the `unsync` flavors of `OnceCell` / `Lazy` should not require my type to be `Sync`. In fact, looking at the reference docs, [`unsync::OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/unsync/struct.OnceCell.html) itself doesn't seem to require `T: Sync`. It looks like it is rather imposed by the compiler because of the `static`, because using a local `let not_global_data: Lazy<TypeNotSync> = ...` inside a function compiles. However, this defeats the purpose of using `OnceCell` -- after all, the goal was to get a "lazy static".

So the question becomes: How can `OnceCell` be used in combination with a non-sync type?

Comment: @cafce25 Well, the `lazy_static` crate has been deprecated in favor of `once_cell` and this part of the documentation literally starts with _this is essentially the lazy_static! macro, ...._ suggesting that it is closely related.

Comment: Yes because a `sync::Lazy` amongst one of it's features provides a macroless alternative to `lazy_static`, that doesn't mean that that is it's main or only purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot.

If a type is not `Sync`, is it not safe to have multiple shared references to it in different threads. `OnceCell` let you do that, so it is not safe to use in `static` with non-`Sync` types, by the definition of `Sync`.

Take `RefCell`, for example: if you put it in a `static`, even behind a `OnceCell`, you can modify it concurrently from multiple threads and cause a data race. `OnceCell` does not change that. It only affects the *initialization* of the type.

If you have a type that is neither `Sync` nor `Send`, then you cannot use it in `static` safely. A possibility (maybe implemented in some crate) is to have a static with it (unsafely) with only one thread allowed to use it, and send commands (and receive back results) to this thread via channels.

If the type is not `Sync` but is `Send`, you can use a `Mutex`. It has the unique property of making non-`Sync` (but `Send`) types `Sync`, because it never yields shared references to them: all it allows is mutable references, not concurrently.

Comment: So this means that `unsync::OnceCell` (and `unsync::Lazy`) can basically never be assigned to a static variable, right? So basically it has to be `sync::Lazy<Mutex<T>>`. Or do you mean `Mutex<unsync::Lazy<T>>`?

Comment: @bluenote10 No, I meant `sync::Lazy<Mutex<T>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `!Sync` means a type cannot safely be accessed from multiple threads a plain `static` obviously cannot safely hold such a value since it can be accessed from all threads.
The obvious usecase for a `std::cell::OnceCell`/`once_cell::unsync::OnceCell` are thread local statics:

```rust
thread_local!{
    static X: OnceCell<TypeNotSync> = OnceCell::new();
}
// use `X` with one instance per thread.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`thread_local`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html) to create non-sync static values.

```rs
thread_local! {
    static GLOBAL_DATA: Lazy<TypeNotSync> = Lazy::new(|| 
        unimplemented!()
    );
}
```

This is pretty useless, though, since `thread_local` already lazily initializes the values.

The non-Sync types in `once_cell` are mostly useful for cases where you do not know if or when a value will be initialized.

```rs
fn main() {
    let global_data: Lazy<String> = Lazy::new(||
        "initialization".to_string()
    );

    for _ in 0..4 {
        if rand::random() {
            println!("{}", *global_data);
        } else {
            println!("no initialization");
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to separate initialization logic from the rest, which may create clearer code, as well as remove the requirement of `mut` from initialization.

You can also pass this around opaquely as `impl Deref<Target = String>` without making `Lazy` visible in the API. It's also a good type to express an expensive deref.